# Partitioning a string to get a list in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, list

I have the following String :

```
def s="txtimgtxtvdd"
```

i want to extract a list from the String above as following

```
def l=["txt","img","txt","vdd"]
```

Each 3 consecutive letters is an item of list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collate` (and `toList` to split the string into a list of chars)

```
def part = 'txtimgtxtvdd'.toList().collate( 3 )*.join()
assert part == ['txt', 'img', 'txt', 'vdd']
```

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Note that for `"txtimgtxtvdds"` this will give you `['txt', 'img', 'txt', 'vdd', 's']`.  If you don't want any _"remainder"_ characters in the list, you can call `collate( 3, false )`